# Identify new data based on ID and Date

Tags: sql, ms-access

The following SQL query does not detect change in my Table :

```
SELECT ID FROM Test WHERE TheDate=#21/10/2021#  AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT ID FROM Test WHERE TheDate=DateAdd("d", -1, #21/10/2021#))
```

For example with this table :

```
TheDate     ID
21/10/2021  1
21/10/2021  7
20/10/2021  1
20/10/2021  2
20/10/2021  3
19/10/2021  3
18/10/2021  3
```

**The Above Query should return 7.**

My goal is to retrieve New ID that does not exist 1 Day before.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists records from that date. Try using `IN`:

```sql
SELECT ID From Test WHERE TheDate=#21/10/2021# AND ID NOT IN
(SELECT ID FROM Test WHERE TheDate=DateAdd("d", -1, #21/10/2021#))
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT ID From Test WHERE TheDate=#2021/10/21# AND ID NOT IN
(SELECT ID FROM Test WHERE TheDate=DateAdd("d", -1, #2021/10/21#))
```

[image]

Comment: And using 2021 in your test data - all your records are in 2022.

Comment: Yes it does. But perhaps you need the ISO sequence for the date. See extended answer, please.

Comment: Ok Gustav, `NOT IN` does not work if I have empty field. So I managed to fix it ! Thank you !